# How to achieve Infinite scrolling behaviour in Staggered Grid using jetpack compose?

Tags: pagination, android-jetpack-compose, staggered-gridview

Infinite scrolling in JetPackCompose for staggered grid layout

> I have tried one approach where I was checking the last item and was fetching more items, but its performance is very poor. Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.